# System.FormatException: 24201: Latitude values must be between -90 and 90 degrees

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, geolocation

### UPDATE

Problem was user's locale!
I have sorted the issue with

```
double lat = double.Parse(Request.Form["lat"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

### Actual question

This is my first attempt to implement location on my mobile site.  I'm getting the user's location from their phone with w3 geolocation API and convert it to double then store it as float in sqlserver.

In most cases it works fine but in some cases the coordinates provided by the phone are quite long.  For example latitude may be `3.1234567890123` so 14 numbers after the dot.

This gets saved as `3.1234567890123+E16` and causes error in the title when I try to calculate distance of user to certain point.

What is the best way to avoid it? Should I trim input from the user to a certain length so it would be converted properly?

### Method to get and save data

```
double lat = Convert.ToDouble(Request.Form["lat"]);
double lng = Convert.ToDouble(Request.Form["lng"]);
user.UpdateMyLocationCoordinates(user.id, lat, lng);

public void UpdateMyLocationCoordinates(int userId, double lat, double lng)
{
    SiteDbHelper db = new SiteDbHelper();
    List<SqlParameter> sqlParameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
    sqlParameters.Add(db.CreateParameter("@userId", SqlDbType.Int, userId));
    sqlParameters.Add(db.CreateParameter("@latitude", SqlDbType.Float, lat));
    sqlParameters.Add(db.CreateParameter("@longitude", SqlDbType.Float, lng));
    db.UpdateInsertDeleteReturnAffectedRowCount ("SocialSiteUser_UpdateMyLocationCoordinates", CommandType.StoredProcedure, sqlParameters);
}
```

### CreateParameter

```
public SqlParameter CreateParameter(string name, SqlDbType type, double value)
{
    SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter(name, value);
    param.SqlDbType = type;
    return param;
}
```

### SP o store data is

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SocialSiteUser_UpdateMyLocationCoordinates]
@userId int,
@latitude float,
@longitude float
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    update domains_users set latitude=@latitude, longitude=@longitude where id=@userId
END
```

Comment: You should post your input, the calculation you run, and the actual part where you are formatting the result.

Comment: Too many digits has little to do with the `-90 ... 90` range.

Comment: I'm posting from my phone but updated the question with exact latitude input. Will update rest a bit layer

Comment: `E+16` is your problem. Are you losing the decimal point somewhere?

Comment: I am converting input to double and saving to SQL server. Data type is float in SQL server column

Comment: Paramater in stored prodecuee is @lat float

Comment: The next question: what calls your stored procedure and what data type is it passing?  In other words, are you converting it to a varchar/char type and then trying to pass it to the procedure?

Comment: I have update my question with details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was user's locale! I have sorted the issue with

```
 double lat = double.Parse(Request.Form["lat"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

While `3.1234567890123+E16` is a valid float, it is a lot larger than 90, so isn't a valid latitude, which do have to lie between `-90` and `+90` degrees.

In addition, `3.1234567890123` is actually `3.1234567890123+E01`, so I'm not sure how it is getting multiplied by `10^16` in the conversion to become `3.1234567890123+E16`.

Comment: actual stored values are 3.9951341674225E+16, 3.27377879977052E+16

Comment: @nLL Those aren't valid latitudes (or longitudes) - What is the exact string in Request["lat"]?

Comment: @nLL for instance 3.9951341674225E+16 is roughly equivalent to 39951341674225000 (we only have a total of 14 digits of precision in the examples you give), so if you have  17-digit number with no decimal, it's going to be X.XXXXE+16 in scientific notation.

Comment: thanks i have got in touch with user and doing tests with them to see whats going on. I will update further.

Comment: At last! I was able to get it working by using "@lat float(53)" instead of "@lat float" in SP